# Tangent to subvariety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X_1, X_2, Y \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be varieties. Suppose that $X_2 \subset X_1$ is a subvariety. Assume that $Y$ is tangent to $X_1$ along a variety $Z$. Is it always true that $Y$ is tangent to $X_2$ along $X_2 \cap Z$? If not, does it help if $X_1$ is a hypersurface and $Y$ is linear?

Answer (score 1):

I believe not. It's easiest to think of this in $\Bbb A^3\subset\Bbb P^3$: Let $X_1 = \{z=0\}$, $X_2 = \{x=z=0\}$, $Z = \{y=z=0\}$, and $Y=\{z-y^2=0\}$. [So, to put it all in $\Bbb P^3$, homogenize the equation for $Y$.] $Y$ is tangent to $X_1$ along the $x$-axis, i.e., along $Z$. But $Y$ is *not* tangent to the $y$-axis, $X_2$, at the origin (or $[0,0,0,1]$).